# foreign key how to use join with 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys

Im trying to make an list off all users registered to a specific cursus i've been looking into the join query but i cant figure out how it works and everything ill try is not working so far. this is what i have so far:

```
      <?php
        $cursus2 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cursus JOIN Cursist"));
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $cursus2);
        $amount = mysqli_affected_rows($con);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
          $Cursist = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        echo $Cursist['username']. "<br />";
      }?>
```

I want an output off all the usernames that are connected with the cursus in the bridge table.

DB structure:

```
**Cursist Table**     
-------------
id    username
-------------
1     name1
2     name2
3     name3
4     name4

**cursus Table**
-------------
id    name
-------------
1     PHP
2     JAVA
3     HTML
4     RUBY

**Bridge**
-------------
Cursus_cursusCode    Cursist_id
-------------
1     1
1     2
1     3
1     4
2     1
2     2
3     3
3     4
4     1
4     2
```

the query that was closed is this one i think:

```
SELECT * FROM cursus 
JOIN cursist ON cursist.id=cursus.cursus_cursusCode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two joins, not one :

```
SELECT *
FROM Cursist t
INNER JOIN Bridge b
 ON(t.id = b.cursist_id)
INNER JOIN Cursos s
 ON(b.Cursus_cursusCode = s.id)
```

If you are only intrested on the username, you don't need to select anything from cursus table, so you can do this:

```
SELECT t.username 
FROM Cursist t
INNER JOIN Bridge b
 ON(t.id = b.cursist_id)
```

Can also be done with EXISTS() :

```
SELECT t.user_name
FROM Cursist t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Bridge B
             WHERE t.id = b.cursist_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT c2.username,c1.name 
FROM bridge b, cursus c1, Cursist c2
WHERE b.Cursus_cursusCode=c1.id AND b.Cursist_id=c2.id
```

You can check it [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/071e9/5)

Comment: Firstly, its the same answer as mine, the only difference is that you WRONGLY provided him implicit join syntax, which shouldn't be used! When answering question use only the EXPLICIT join syntax's!

Comment: Congratulations! @sagi, But you must improved line 5 of your fisrt query:
`INNER JOIN Cursos s`, 
The Cursos table doesn't exist, I was doing the sqlfidle while you had posted your queries. I just want to help